# How to pass -mwindows to cargo build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to build a Windows Desktop app, and pass `-mwindows` to rustc during `cargo build`. I followed this [link](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/544), but did not find out how to do it. Do I need to create a `./cargo` config file or pass some command via `cargo rustc`?

Comment: Did you read up on the [related issue #595](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/595), which adds `cargo rustc`?

Comment: @Shepmaster it took me a lot of time to figure it out... the `cargo rustc --help` is hard to understand. Maybe I am not that smart kind of guy. I stiil do not understand why do we need a separate `cargo rustc` command.

Comment: `[--]` really got me.

Answer (score 4):

use `cargo rustc [options] [--] [<opts>...]`.

```
  cargo rustc -- -C link-args=-mwindows
```

You can type `rustc -C help` to see more options.

Comment: haw can we get "--release" and "-mwindows"?

Comment: `cargo rustc --release -- -C link-args=-mwindows` thanks to https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cargo-rustc-how-do-you-fetch-the-dependencies/1557/6

Answer (score 1):

As of [Rust 1.18](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/06/08/Rust-1.18.html) you can use the crate attribute `#![windows_subsystem]` to pass this flag to the linker.

The two values accepted are `#![windows_subsystem = "console"]` and `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]`.

See [Rust RFC 1665](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1665-windows-subsystem.md) for details.